# Password Protecting One View Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to protect just one page on one of my ASP.NET MVC4 web sites I am working on. It is one single view but the rest of the site needs to be accessible. This doesn't have to be extremely secure password protection, just something that can keep off most people from trying to use said page.

What would be the best way of going about this? Either in code or IIS would work..

Thank you!

Comment: What is your question? What problem are you running into as you try to do this?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Have you looked into any options? Is there a reason that the authentication framework that comes with ASP.NET MVC wouldn't work for you? You'll find that you get better answers if you specify what you've tried, and what specific aspect of it eludes you. There are entire articles written that answer questions like this, and most people don't want to re-write a new one just for you.

Comment: Use the built-in authentication. It doesn't matter if you're protecting just one view or many. If you don't want to do that, then you're on your own for implementing a solution.